# Can VS Code list all JSDoc missing comments?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

In VS Code, I have `// @ts-check` enabled at the top of my JavaScript file. I have fixed all of the problem that it found. However, it has inspired me to add JSDoc comments to my file. I have been going through the file looking for the three gray dots (...) under parameters that need to have JSDoc comments added to, as shown in this image.

[image]

However, I don't want to miss any of these. Is there a way for VS Code to list all of the JSDoc issues in the in the problems section?